# Next.jsL How to dynamically insert critical css in _document.js/_app.js?

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am using native next.js style approach which is css modules.
I have some global css variables that should be added to app, such as:

```
// theme.css
:root {
    --PRIMARY_COLOR: #504f94;
    --PRIMARY_BRIGHT_COLOR: #926ba7;
    --PRIMARY_COLOR_ACCENT: #3e3d81;

    --SECONDARY_COLOR: #102f31;
    --SECONDARY_COLOR_ACCENT: #1d2020;

}
```

The issue is that I have several such theme files in my project and I need to use only one of them depending on the environment variable.

So it is server-side decision to pick one of files and import it.

Then my question is - what can I do in custom _document.js or _app.js to insert styles dynamically after I decide which theme I need?
Also I don't want to have other themes code in my bundle

Answer (score 0):

My final solution:

1. In _document.js run script that reads content of file with css variables using `fs` module.
2. Create `style` tag with content of file we read previously.
3. Insert  tag in _document component.

```
import React from 'react';
import { default as Document, Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';
const path = require('path');
const { getRootDirPathEnvVariable } = require('../infrastructure');

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
    render() {
        return (
            <Html lang="en">
                <Head/>
                <body>
                    { this.props.tagToInject}
                    <Main />
                    <NextScript />
                </body>
            </Html>
        );
    }
}


MyDocument.getInitialProps = async ( ctx ) => {

    const cssFileContent = fs
        .readFileSync( path.join( getRootDirPathEnvVariable(), 'src', 'theme.css' ) )
        .toString();

    const tagToInject = (
        <style
                className="css-configs"
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ {
                    __html: value,
                } }
         />
    )

    const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;

    ctx.renderPage = () => originalRenderPage( {
        enhanceApp: ( App ) => function EnhanceApp( props ) {
            return (
                <App
                    jsonConfigs={ jsonConfigs }
                    { ...props }
                />
            );
        },
    } );

    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps( ctx );

    return {
        ...initialProps,
        tagToInject,
    };
};
```